# gson TypeToken classNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, gson

webserver: tomcat

web framework: spring3

I use gson-2.3.1

follow error log

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysite.chart.**ChartCtrl$2**
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
**at com.mysite.chart.ChartCtrl.msyData(ChartCtrl.java:278)**
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

and ChartCtrl 278 line is follow

```
Type objType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType();
```

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue, in my case I was importing the wrong class which somehow was available in the classpath for IDE but not on runtime.

Replace the below one:

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
```

With this one:

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

Comment: Considering how generic question this is, this is most likely correct answer. From where the IDEs are taking the worng com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken is hard to s say  -I tried super simple project jsut with gson jar in pom,and still it was in autosuggestion

Answer (score 0):

[ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is thrown when no definition for the class with the specified name could be found, and by looking at stacktrace, since it contains $2 it makes me believe you (or someone) are using some inner class or anonymous inner class which uses some library that is not package in your .war file.

In this specific case, I guess you didn't package gson jar, which contains [TypeToken](http://javadox.com/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.1/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) class, in your WEB-INF/lib folder. Can you confirm?

Comment: gson-2.3.1.jar is in WEB-INF/lib.

Same Class's other method use it but work fine.

Comment: If this is the case then as I mentioned, does your class has some inner class or anonymous class? This is typical classpath problem that is resolved at runtime.

Comment: I dont's use inner class.
ChartCtrl class doesn't have inner class.

I don't know why find ChartCtrl$2 class..

Comment: Can you attach the code for ChartCtrl, if possible?